# How to lock a door using a battery-powered lock, without an outside handle?

Tags: electrical-engineering, battery

Scenario:

- Door has a flush outside, without any knobs or handles.  The door is opened by pushing it.  When the door is left un-pushed, the door closes itself as there is a door-closer arm attached to it.  So there is no reason to have locks/handles on the outside.  But there is a pull-bar to pull the door from the inside.
- Sometimes one wants to lock the door from the outside as one leaves.  For such a situation, the person uses a remote control, and presses a key.  The key will transmit some radio signal that the battery-powered locking mechanism inside the door will then receive, to then lock the door from the inside.
- The only part exposed on the outside is a signal receiver glass, and a box to swap the battery in case the battery is dead.

**Question:** How to implement this locking scenario?

---

What I know so far:

- There are such *digital* locks, but the problem is that they have a full interface on the outside, such as door handles.  But I don't want such interfaces at all.  They're all designed to open the door by, eventually, rotating the handle.  This is wasteful for me, as, in my scenario the door is opened by simply pushing it from outside, or pulling it from inside.

What I don't know so far:

- Is there any simple battery-powered locking system, that only offer locking/unlocking via remote presses, without all the other mechanical fluff that are commonly used in wooden doors (e.g. handle, tongue, etc)?

Comment: Doors with electromagnets on the door frame itself (no tongue etc) and a proximity key fob to deactivate the magnet to unlock the door sounds like what you're describing.

Comment: But here locking requires the magnet to be ON for all the period the door is locked, right?

Comment: you could also use a spring to make a clutch system, where when power is applied an electromagnet is created, pulling the locking (permanent) magnet, compressing the spring, and releasing contact between the permanent magnet and steel component of the door frame.

Comment: Is there such things already implemented?  Before I go invent them my own?  Because my main focus is the door.  It'd be nice if I don't have to invent hammers too.

Comment: probably. embrace google or commercial hardware stores.

Comment: You are asking ppeople who reinvent hammers (wheels, etc.) just for the fun of it!

Comment: security doors torun off the electromagnet with an RFID card.  It's nothing to do the opposite.  And there are probably legions of arduino-heads who could make a bluetooth or 802.11 receiver to turn on an electromagnet or rotate a deadbolt.  All you[re really talking about is a hotel wifi lock without a doorknob on the outside.  That said, a door without hardware is not elegant, it's confusing to people who expect hardware.

Comment: @TigerGuy - what if I don't want to do it with arduino.  E.g. it is too expensive.  It is cheaper to have a ready made product (smaller circuit).

Comment: How secure do you want this to be?  Modern garage door systems use "rolling codes" for a reason.  You aren't going to re-invent that without a decent amount of hardware/software investment, so might as well buy a premade system.

Comment: Next thing: you **cannot** make the battery accessible from the outside, or I will come by & steal the battery, and then how will you get access?  you're not going to be carrying a spare battery with you at all times.  At the very least, you need a mains-powered lock with battery backup.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - got examples of such pre-made system?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - batteries are cheap.  It's much cheaper to install a new battery, in replacement of a stolen one, as opposed to break the door to replace the lock due to a dead battery.  This approach is already adopted by many security doors.

Comment: @caveman not if you come home late at night and don't have a spare battery in your pocket.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - batter theft is extremely unlikely, and, in extreme rare cases when it happens, is still orders of magnitude lesser of a problem than coming back home late at night to find out that the battery is dead, and its replacement requires opening the door.  Instead of getting 4 AA betteries late at night, you'll need to drill the door and annoy the neighbours.